# Trying to subclass GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rewardedvideoad, nsobjectprotocol

I am trying to create a singleton class, subclass of `GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate`. Something like this:

```
import Foundation
import GoogleMobileAds
class MyAdsManager : GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate {
    private let id : String = "MY_ADMOB_ID"
    private var selector : (()->Void)?
    static let instance: MyAdsManager = {
        return MyAdsManager()
    }()

    class func getInstance() -> MyAdsManager {
        return instance
    }

    private init() {
        loadVideo()
    }

    //more methods
}
```

The error message is:

`Type 'MyAdsManager' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'`

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly, but implementing `NSObjectProtocol` is not something I am looking for...

Thank you in advance people.

Comment: That was fast and yes, it works. Thank you. Why is that `NSObject`? Sorry, I'm still learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
class MyAdsManager : GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate
```

with

```
class MyAdsManager : NSObject, GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate
```

---

Reason

`GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate` inherits from `NSObjectProtocol`  so you have to implement all methods listed in `NSObjectProtocol` and since these methods are implemented inside `NSObject` subclasses so it does the job for you